# Keep a line of text as a single line - wrap the whole line or none at all

Tags: html, css

I'd like to keep a line of text together such that either the whole line drops down a line or none at all

**Acceptable**

```
How do I wrap this line of text - asked by Peter 2 days ago
```

**Acceptable**

```
How do I wrap this line of text 
- asked by Peter 2 days ago
```

**Not acceptable**

```
How do I wrap this line of text - asked by Peter 
2 days ago
```

Is this achievable in CSS?

Comment: How are your lines expressed in markup?  Are you just making an assumption of a new line because it contains a hyphen?

Comment: @DoctorMick - no assumptions of newlines and the markup is completely open to anything - @Gus' answer has nailed it for me though - ty

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can use `white-space: nowrap;` to define this behaviour:

```
// HTML:
```

```css
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap ;
}
```

```html
<p>
      <span class="nowrap">How do I wrap this line of text</span>
      <span class="nowrap">- asked by Peter 2 days ago</span>
    </p>
```

```
// CSS:
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap ;
}
```

Comment: This works well unless the amount of text within the span cannot be displayed on one line in which case it is cut off. Something to think about on small/mobile screens and responsive sites.

Comment: @PaulHiles you could use media breakpoint detector to remove the nowrap on smaller screens

Answer (score 2):

You could also put non-breaking spaces (&nbsp;) in lieu of the spaces so that they're forced to stay together.

```
How do I wrap this line of text
-&nbsp;asked&nbsp;by&nbsp;Peter&nbsp;2&nbsp;days&nbsp;ago
```

Comment: As Paul Hiles noted above this also works well unless the amount of text cannot be displayed on one line in which case it is cut off.